# Writing List to specific column in excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have data in list and I want to write the list to specific columns in excel.
I have list = [Apple, Pear, Fruit]
I need to write this to excel as Column A = Apple, Column C = Pear, Column F = Fruit.
When I use append, it is writing to Column A, B and C. But that's not what I want.

Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl

path = r"C:\Folder\Filename.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(path)
sheet = wb[sheet_name]
list = [Apple, Pear, Fruit]
sheet.append(list)
```

Comment: Are Apple, Pear, Fruit strings or cell elements? If strings quote the elements. Code above will not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 4 ways to set values in different columns in a row using *openpyxl*.
These will create a row with Column A = Apple, Column C = Pear, and Column F = Fruit.

1. Append new row with list of values (use *None* value to skip a column)

```
fruit = ['Apple', None, 'Pear', None, None, 'Fruit']
sheet.append(fruit)
```

2. Append new row using dictionary specifying row letter.

```
fruit = {'A' : 'Apple', 'C' : 'Pear', 'F' : 'Fruit'}
sheet.append(fruit)
```

3. set values in the cells using absolute referencing

```
sheet["A1"] = "Apple"
sheet["C1"] = "Pear"
sheet["F1"] = "Fruit"
```

4. Specify the column and next row by index

```
row = sheet.max_row + 1
sheet.cell(row=row, column=1, value="Apple")  # => column A
sheet.cell(row=row, column=3, value="Pear")   # => column C
sheet.cell(row=row, column=6, value="Fruit")  # => column F
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `xlsxwriter`:

```
import xlsxwriter

fdata = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Fruit']
column = [1, 3, 6]

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx') as workbook:
    file = workbook.add_worksheet()

    for col, data in zip(column, fdata):
        file.write(0, col-1, data)
```